# What should be the Maximum Timeout in C# WWF(WorkFlow) for calling Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, workflow

I am getting timeout error while execution the WebAPI through WWF(Workflow).
and I am not able to determine whether My workflow getting timeout or Web API which i am calling through Workflow.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How much the maximum timeout i can set in WWF(Workflow) while calling WEB API.